# Is there any other language which compiles to FASM?

Tags: compiler-construction, x86, ghc, backend, fasm

FASM is the fastest and most efficient x86/64 assembler out there, and I'm using it as the backend for the compiler of a new language I'm writing.

Since I only use Ubuntu the FASM code which my compiler generates is Linux specific. However I want to make it cross-platform compatible.

Hence I first want to study other compilers which use FASM as a backend too. AFAIK only the Glasgow Haskell Compiler (GHC) does this.

Does anyone know any other compiler which produces cross-platform compatible FASM code? Preferable one which has good documentation.

Comment: 90% of what you emit should be opcode mnemonics, and those are the same for all assemblers (there are two different ways to write out arguments, Intel vs. AT&T, but for any given platform, there are assemblers supporting both). Also: GHC is the **Glasgow** Haskell Compiler, it has nothing to do with GNU. Perhaps you should put some more time into research ...

Comment: @delnan - Thank you. I stand corrected.

Comment: I know of a few high level programs that use fasm for runtime asm generation, because it provides a dll that makes it much easier. These just generate single functions though, which is not what you want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK [PureBasic](http://www.purebasic.com/) uses FASM as a backend.